# Two arrays alignment into one array

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, math

How could I align (synchronize) two arrays of data, perhaps with different size? I have read about correlation function and cross correlation function, but I do not understand what to use(.

```
data1 [1..n]
data2 [1..m]
dataAlignmetntArray(data1, data2)=[] ???
```

Could any one provide some ideas (any language mathlab c will be ok - I will understand)

ok I have read about xcorr in mathlab and do the following

```
x = [0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6];
y = [0 .15 1.12 2.36 2.36 1.46 .49 .06 0 3];
res = xcorr(x,y)
```

but I don't think that result is what I am need (I am new at this field of experiment(()
also I have read about correlation using FFt but there are some conditions on n and m (length of arrays) and I don't think that my real data will meet them (length of data1 = length of data 2 and 
 this length must be a power of 2). So I go there for simple explanation and perhaps some ideas

Comment: Almost always you shouldn't specify more than one language. Pick one. And did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show theirs.

Comment: What kind of alignment do you require? In one axis, two or maybe with scaling and rotations?

Comment: I think that I need alignment by one axis (this arrays have 1 dimension) but they could have different length so a scaling alignment must be to?  (sorry for this "alignment for dummies question)")